# receiving data url and trigger signal django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm getting a code in the url by post and do a get to receive data from a webserver.
With the amount received by get I update a field related to the status of my model. I'm using signals
The method on_paid () that updates the field model fails to be triggered. The prints are not displayed.
the URL is correctly because the POST and the data are coming. only the signal not being fired
Do not know what it could be wrong.

signal.py -

```
from django.dispatch import Signal
from .codes import codes

notification_received = Signal(providing_args=['notification'])
transaction_received = Signal(providing_args=['transaction'])

transaction_waiting = Signal()
transaction_analysis = Signal()
transaction_paid = Signal()
transaction_available = Signal()
transaction_dispute = Signal()
transaction_returned = Signal()
transaction_canceled = Signal()
transaction_unknown = Signal()


def dispatch_transaction(sender, **kwargs):
    transaction = kwargs.pop('transaction')
    status = int(transaction['status'])

signals = {
    codes.waiting: transaction_waiting,
    codes.analysis: transaction_analysis,
    codes.paid: transaction_paid,
    codes.available: transaction_available,
    codes.dispute: transaction_dispute,
    codes.returned: transaction_returned,
    codes.canceled: transaction_canceled
}

signals \
    .get(status, transaction_unknown) \
    .send(sender=None, transaction=transaction)

transaction_received.connect(dispatch_transaction)
```

model.py

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    # .....
    statuspagamento = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=u"Status do PagSeguro")    


from djpg.signals import transaction_paid

def on_paid(sender, **kwargs):
    transaction = kwargs.pop('transaction')
    p = Pedido.objects.get(reference=transaction['reference'])
    ref = transaction['reference']
    status = transaction['status']
    print "HELLO WORD"
    print "imprimindo p ", p
    # .....

transaction_paid.connect(on_paid)
```

Comment: the prints "hello world" is not displayed on the screen